# JOOQ: fetchGroups() always returns list with only one element

Tags: jooq

I'm new to JOOQ and currently fail to map a joined query to `Map<K, List<V>>`: the list always only contains one element.

Here's my code:

```
        DSL.using(...)
            .select(ORDER.fields())
            .select(ORDER_ITEM_ARTICLE.fields())
            .from(ORDER)
            .leftOuterJoin(ORDER_ITEM_ARTICLE).on(ORDER.ID.eq(ORDER_ITEM_ARTICLE.ORDER_ID))

            // to Map<InOutOrder, List<OrderItemArticle>>
            .fetchGroups(
                r -> r.into(ORDER).into(InOutOrder.class),
                r -> r.into(ORDER_ITEM_ARTICLE).into(OrderItemArticle.class)
            )

            // map to InOutOrder
            .entrySet().stream().map( e -> {

                // e.getValue() always returns list with only 1 element?!
                e.getKey().articles = e.getValue();
                return e.getKey();
            })
            .collect(Collectors.toList())
            ;
```

Say I have 1 row in `ORDER` and 2 corresponding rows in `ORDER_ITEM_ARTICLE`. Running the SQL returned by `.getSQL()` (after `.fetchGroups()`), returns me 2 rows as expected, so I assumed the `fetchGroups()` call will populate my list with two entries as well?!

What am I missing?

Thanks!

---

Update:

As requested, the `InOutOrder` class:

```
public class InOutOrder extends Order {
    public List<OrderItemArticle> articles;
    public List<OrderItemOther> others;
    public List<OrderItemCost> costs;
    public List<OrderContact> contacts;
    public List<EmailJob> emailJobs;
}
```

So this is just an extension of the JOOQ POJO class and is used for JSON communication with the API clients...

Comment: Can you post your `InOutOrder` class?

Comment: @LukasEder thanks for your fast response! I've added the requested information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fetchGroups()` simply puts objects in a `LinkedHashMap`. You have to adhere to the usual `Map` contract, which means implementing `equals()` and `hashCode()`. Without it, each object you're creating (or which jOOQ is creating for you) will use identity comparison, so you get every "value" only once in the result.